# Segmentation fault when free the variable after using strt_ok

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

I have segmentation fault when executing this simple program (it is just a light version to reproduce the error).

```
//   gcc main.c -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic
//   ./a.out

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h> // uint32_t

int main(){

    char* rest = (char*)malloc(128 * sizeof(char));
    char* token= (char*)malloc(128 * sizeof(char)); 
    strcpy(rest,"Something_else");
    token = strtok_r(rest, "_", &rest);
    printf("%s\n", token);
    free(token);
    free(rest);
    return 0;
}
```

The `free` of the variable `token` does not give any error. The `free` of the variable `rest` gives me always a segmentation fault every time I use the function `strok_r`. What is going on? Any suggestion?
No warnings are prompt at compilation time.

**Question**:

How to re-write this simple code **properly**?

Comment: You are using `rest` both as save pointer and as string to tokenise. That means that `rest` will now point to `"else"`, but your `free` needs the exact pointer that was allocated, namely the one to `"Something_else"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need memory for the sentence, `token` and `rest` are just pointers.

And using a `while` loop, you can see all the tokens:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h> // uint32_t

int main(){

    char* rest , *token;
    char* setence= malloc(128 * sizeof(char)); 

    strcpy(setence, "Some_thing_else");

    token = strtok_r(setence, "_", &rest);

    while (token) 
    {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok_r(NULL, "_", &rest);          
    }

    free(setence);

    return 0;
}
```

Will give:

```
Some
thing
else
```

Answer (score 2):

You should neither allocate nor free the variable 'rest'. strtok_r uses its third argument to store where it got to in the original string. 
So:

```
char* rest;
char* copy= (char*)malloc(128 * sizeof(char)); 
strcpy(copy,"Something_else");
char* token = strtok_r(copy, "_", &rest); 
// ...
free( copy);  // don't free token or rest
```

Comment: Now you are writing to an uninitialized pointer with `strcpy`.

Comment: @rtoijala ... and leaking the memory from `char* token= (char*)malloc(128 * sizeof(char)); `.

Comment: the solution is to NOT allocate a pointer? does `strtok_r` allocate it internally?

Comment: @Leos313: No allocation is happening for either the resulting token or the save pointer: These are just pointers into the original string. The tokens aren't copies, they are "views" into the string. That's fast, but comes at the cost that the original string is altered in the process.

Comment: in the third line of your code, you are coping a string in a not allocated pointer. Is it correct??

Comment: No, that isn't correct, as was already pointed out. Look at Matthieu's answer, which describes a typical and correct use of `strtok_r`.